# adaptative threshold opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

hi all i use cvAdaptiveThreshold  someone can explain me how work this function how determined the block_size and the param1 ?

```
IplImage *imgPicThres = cvCreateImage(cvSize(img_roi->width, img_roi->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

cvAdaptiveThreshold(img_roi, imgPicThres,255,CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV,blocks_size,param1);
```

Comment: If this question has been successfully answered, consider selecting the official answer by clicking on the checkbox near it. If not, consider adding your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

`cvAdaptiveThreshold()` is [described in the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?#adaptivethreshold):

> [It transforms a grayscale image to binary image](https://web.archive.org/web/20150418185403/http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~bensapp/opencvdocs/ref/opencvref_cv.htm#decl_cvAdaptiveThreshold).

Comment: @karlphilip the links are no more online, could you update your answer (and maybe include some informations in the answer)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Basj This is a 6 year old answer not worth saving.

Comment: It is worth @karlphilip, we arrive to this answer when googling about adaptive thresholding ;)